# Add Data to Radar Chart Through User Input with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, chart.js

I want the user to add data to a Radar Chart in React through User Input. I tried different methods but it just does not work or the chart does not get displayed. Here is the code

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    RadialLinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Filler,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
} from "chart.js";
import { Radar } from "react-chartjs-2";

function App() {
  ChartJS.register(
    RadialLinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Filler,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
  );

const data = {
    labels: ["Business 1", "Business 2", "Business 3"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Number of Businesses",
        data: [1300, 400, 160],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Radar data={data} />

      <form>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Label' />
        <input type='text' placeholder='Dataset' />
        <button>Add Data</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I would really appreciate any help or solution.

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/radar-chart-react-shyv49 Please have a look at this